# Getting error on calling Channels.history api

Tags: slack-api

This is the api: https://slack.com/api/channels.history

**Request**:

```
token=&channel=(Removing the token and channel name for privacy)
```

**Response**:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "not_authed"
}
```

The token I have provided is correct, can someone tell what can be the issue here?

Comment: please modify question and povide an working example that creates the stated issue. Also, post what you tried to solve it yourself. Give software package names and version numbers.